# How to mock only one exported function in jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to mock a single function in my test inside a module.
This is the module, where I need to mock only `generateServerSeed`

```
// seeds.js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const generateServerSeed = function () {
    return crypto.randomBytes(4).toString('base64');
};

const hashServerSeed = function (serverSeed) {
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
    hash.update(serverSeed);
    return hash.digest('hex');
};

module.exports = {
    hashServerSeed,
    generateServerSeed
};
```

This is the function, where this module is used:

```
// blabla.js
import { generateServerSeed, hashServerSeed } from './seeds';

const VeryImportantFunction = () => {
    const serverSeed = generateServerSeed();
    const hash = hashServerSeed(serverSeed);
    return hash;
};

module.exports = {
    VeryImportantFunction
};
```

and this is my test file

```
jest.mock('../seeds');
import { VeryImportantFunction } from '../blabla';
import { generateServerSeed } from '../seeds';
const { hashServerSeed } = jest.requireActual('../seeds');

describe('Playground', function () {
    test('blabla', () => {
        generateServerSeed.mockReturnValue('1234567890ABCDEF');
        expect(VeryImportantFunction()).toBe('f456e02c19ac920...c630bd36cf04b4f57');
    });
});
```

Above I've tried to mock `generateServerSeed`, which is ok. But I was not able to find how to leave the original implementation of `hashServerSeed` using `jest.requireActual`, because in the test function itself I am not explicitly calling that function.

How can I leave `hashServerSeed`'s original implementation and mock only `generateServerSeed` while NOT separating these 2 functions and not using manual mock to keep in simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed mock the `generateServerSeed` method and leave all the original remaining methods of `seeds` using jest [`requireActual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename):

```
import { VeryImportantFunction } from '../blabla';
import { generateServerSeed } from '../seeds';

jest.mock('../seeds', () => {
    // The mock returned only mocks the generateServerSeed method.
    const actual = jest.requireActual('../seeds');

    return {
        ...actual,
        generateServerSeed: jest.fn()
    };
});

describe('Playground', function () {
    test('blabla', () => {
        // Mock the return value.
        generateServerSeed.mockReturnValue('1234567890ABCDEF');

        expect(VeryImportantFunction()).toBe('f456e02c19ac920...c630bd36cf04b4f57');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I understand right, that in `return { ...actual, generateServerSeed: jest.fn()` even though `...actual` is bringing all the functions, generateServerSeed is overwriting the one brought?

Comment: Yes! That's it!